# MySQL - Can't set / reset password for root user properly (CentOS)

Tags: mysql

I have installed MySQL 5.7.2 in CentOS 6.9. In other systems(Debian, Arch) when I installed mysql it prompted for root password at the installation  process but in this case it didn't prompted for a password. So I tried to log in to mysql shell using blank password. But mysql reported *Access Denied* message.

Then I tried to set new password in mysql safe mode.

```
$ service mysqld stop
$ mysql_safe --skip-grant-tables &
$ mysql -u root
mysql > USE mysql;
mysql > UPDATE user SET authentication_string = PASSWORD('mypass') WHERE User='root';
mysql > FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

(Some people instructed to use *password* column. But I didn't find this column in *user* table. So I used *authentication_string* column)

It worked perfectly. I can log in as root in mysql shell using my new password.

Then I installed *phpmyadmin*. When I tried to log in to phpmyadmin with my mysql credentials it reported following error:

> 1862 - Your password has expired. To log in you must change it using a client that supports expired passwords.
>
> mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1862): Your password has expired. To log in you must change it using a client that supports expired passwords.

To solve this I logged in to mysql shell and tried this:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' PASSWORD EXPIRE NEVER;
```

It reported following error:

> ERROR 1820 (HY000): You must reset your password using ALTER USER statement before executing this statement.

**So** I tried following in the mysql shell

```
mysql > ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass';
```

But It reported following error:

> ERROR 1819 (HY000): Your password does not satisfy the current policy requirements

Then I have tried to reset my password using *mysql_secure_installation*. It also reporting same kind of error:

> ... Failed! Error: Your password does not satisfy the current policy requirements

Now I am stuck. What is the problem? How can I solve this issue? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your password does not satisfy the current [policy requirements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/validate-password-plugin.html).

> Assuming that the validate_password plugin is installed, it implements three levels of password checking: LOW, MEDIUM, and STRONG. The default is **MEDIUM**;

Medium is defined as:

> MEDIUM policy adds the conditions that passwords must contain at least 1 numeric character, 1 lowercase character, 1 uppercase character, and 1 special (nonalphanumeric) character.

Use a password that satisfies these requirements, set `validate_password_policy` to `LOW` or disable the password validation plugin.